# Как получить полный путь к файлу на рабочем столе?

Tags: c#, .net

Как получить полный путь к файлу в c#? Допустим, у меня есть файл с названием "text.txt", который находится в папке "Texts" на рабочем столе. Мне нужно вывести его путь в формате "C:/Users/User/название папки/название папки/".

Comment: Вопрос неясен. А какая информация у вас есть на руках?

Comment: @VladD теперь ясен?

Answer (score 4):

Для вашего случая вам для начала нужно узнать путь к Desktop'у текущего юзера. Это делается так:

```
var desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
```

Имея путь к Desktop'у, дальше просто:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(desktopPath, "Texts", "text.txt");
```

Comment: А в чем разница с `Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop`? Тут везде именно ее дают в качестве ответа: https://stackoverflow.com/q/634142/6766879 У меня на ПК выдает и так и так одинаковый путь

Comment: @АндрейNOP: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5612571/276994